# Alias for keycodes in XKB evdev file

Tags: keyboard, alias, xkb

I want to remap "i" to the home button without losing "i" on the alphabet section of the keyboard.

I tried
alias  = ;

but it didn't seem to do anything.

I've tried Autokey but it doesn't work with certain hot key combos in the software, like *+i.

thanks for your help!